# Start a task process wait for first response

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, designer

I'm needing help on the following issue:

The workflow (SP Designer 2013) contains an action 'Start a task process' with parallel assignment. The completion criteria is set to 'Wait for first response'.

In my example the tasks is assigned to 6 people (dynamically), so generating 6 different tasks in the task list. If one of these approves or declines, the workflow continues as intended. But the other 5 task are still open.

Is it possible to close/delete these tasks that are no longer relevant?

If the user still reply, his answer is not used in the flow. The task list is going over 5000 items in no time because these tasks keep in the list.

If we could catch an ID, we could create a flow to delete these non-relevant items in the task list.

Answer (score 0):

You need `End Task Process` after first response

[Parallel approval workflow, where One approval completes the workflow](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2cd81250-1124-4d61-b78d-78e747f7fd64/parallel-approval-workflow-where-one-approval-completes-the-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious).

---

### EDIT

[SharePoint Workflow Approval by Only One Member of a Group](https://threewill.com/sharepoint-workflow-approval-by-only-one-member-of-a-group/)

> In my example the tasks is assigned to 6 people (dynamically), so
> generating 6 different tasks in the task list.

You are assigning users but preferred way is to set SP Group so that you have only one task.

**Add the users in a SP Group. Assign this SP Group as approver Set the tasks to parallel. Uncheck Expand groups. Task emails will be sent to all but only one task assigned to the SP Group will be created. Any member of the group can Approve the task.**

Maybe someone else have better answer to your question

Comment: My workflow is based on SharePoint workflow 2013.
The link refers to the SharePoint workflow 2010 engine.